# "Bring somebody to his knees"

Tags: word-order

> Bring the man who embarrassed your cousin last night in the party of College of Forestry to his knees.

Is it acceptable for the long noun phrase to switch places with the PP *to knees*?

> Bring to knees the man who embarrassed your cousin last night in the party of College of Forestry.

Comment: Did you mean to write *"Bring to **his** knees"* in the second example?

Comment: *the man who embarrassed your cousin yesterday* is just a long noun phrase. It's a clumsy construction here, but grammatically it's perfectly ordinary (as it would be if replaced by, say, **him**). OP's second construction is totally ungrammatical (neither *Bring to knees him* nor *Bring to **his** knees him* are even remotely English)

Comment: *Give **the ELL user from the Philippines who goes by the name of Sherlock on this site** an answer*, someone please.

Comment: I finally have a name for what I'm trying to do here: _Heavy NP Shift_ construction (http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=4398). I only want to know if this is possible with my own example sentence.

Comment: FumbleFingers gave an example sentence that can be reconstructed: _Give an answer to the ELL user from the Phiippines who goes by the name of Sherlock on this site_. The O.P.'s example doesn't work, though, because "Bring to knees" is not grammatical. The idiom needs to be in the form "bring him to his knees" (or "bring her to her knees").

Comment: Can you suggest any alternative that can be applied to my sentence but retains the word _knees_ expressing submission, with the long NP at the end and not in the middle?

Comment: As I was saying, *"Bring to **his** knees the man who embarrassed your cousin last night in the party of the College of Forestry."* is grammatical, while your version is not.

Comment: @snailboat: That's grammatical? I must have misunderstood FumbleFingers' comment then.

Comment: It becomes ungrammatical if you write *him* as FumbleFingers did; I'm not sure what point he was making.  I agree that *Bring to his knees him* is unacceptable.

Comment: @snailboat and Sherlock: Post it as an answer. Between you, you've got the answer. With *his* added, the sentence *is* grammatical, it *is* a "Heavy NP shift". And FF is right that "bring to his knees him" is ungrammatical, because *him* is a very light NP.

Comment: Sorry, posting answers from my phone is difficult.  If you want me to write one, I'm afraid you'll have to wait.

Comment: Yes, it's grammatical, but – egads! – is that ever an ugly sentence. How about: _That man who embarrassed your cousin last night? At the party held at the College of Forestry? We should bring him to his knees!_ Sure that's got two fragments disguised as rhetorical questions, but I still think it reads better. To the O.P.: I don't know why you're trying to shift it around; your original sentence sounds better.

Comment: @J.R. It's no uglier than the original, and to my mind easier to follow. The problem lies in the use of an unusually heavy direct object with an idiom that isn't designed to accommodate it. In ordinary uses, where the DO is fairly light, the "to his knees" piece will be at least as heavy if not heavier. **I** would solve the problem by using a different verb - *humiliate*, perhaps.

Comment: Sherlock, there are also a couple of non-idiomatic uses here. It should at least be *at* the party and *the* College; and actually we'd normally say *the College of Forestry party*.

Comment: @StoneyB: Well, we'd probably at least agree that it's not a huge improvement either way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the "his":

```
Bring to his knees the man who embarrassed your cousin…
```

Then yes, it's grammatically correct, but almost never seen that way. It's generally used to end a clause or sentence forcefully.

You might say that such a powerful phrase… could bring a sentence to its knees.

Answer (score 1):

As meetar says, it's unusual.  If cast that way, it's more the command form. You might find it in say a play about Old England, where the King demands:

"Bring to his knees the man ... ! "

and it would end in an exclamation point.